# Find index of String in String array in Java

Tags: java, string

I have an array

```
String[] values = new String[] {"AB","BC","CD","AE"};
```

I wanna find the index of the String `BC`. I know we can use `indexOf` for integers but wasn't able to find anything simple for string.

Comment: See *"For Object arrays"* in Tunaki's answer on the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a linear search, like:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   if (values[i].equals("BC") {
       index = i;
   }
}
```